# How to set Userdefined homepage in Internet Explorer?

Tags: lumia, internet-explorer

How to add userdefined homepage to Lumia 525? I searched a lot in my phone , but unable to found . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer on windows Phone 8 does not have the concept of a homepage - it will instead restore the tabs that you last had opened; If you close all the tabs, then you just get a blank page.