# How to remove browser "home page" - att.yahoo.com

Tags: 8.0, internet-explorer

I am running Windows Phone 8.0 on a Nokia 820 and I'm finding it has this annoying "att.yahoo.com" web browser "home page," for lack of a better word, and this is with the default IE browser.  I've had other Windows Phone devices and never experienced a "home page" and there is nothing under settings for it, and I really want to get rid of this. The browser keeps going to this page, but I'm not exactly sure when it goes to it, like if I close all tabs, it doesn't appear. If I back out of the browser and go back in, it doesn't appear. But at times, there it is, and it's quite annoying and I have to manually close the tab every time I see it.

Is there some hidden setting for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Userdefined homepage in Internet Explorer?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-to-set-userdefined-homepage-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: If you close the tab or navigate to "somewhere else", does it go back to this homepage when you go back into Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Indrek I don't think it is a duplicate. The question you refereed to was about setting a home page. While this question is about a page that appears due to network operator and it is not a homepage(see my answer to this question for details). The point is **they are two different questions** with different set of answers. One questions answer cannot be an solution to an another.

Comment: @KolappanNathan Fair enough. Seemed similar enough to me (I assumed a forced "home page" by the carrier), but your explanation makes sense. I'll withdraw my close vote.

Answer (score 2):

This is **due to your ISP/network operator**. I have experienced it.

> If I back out of the browser and go back in, it doesn't appear

As I recall, it will appear the first time you open your browser after turning on the mobile data/Wi-Fi. It may also appear when you are accessing the internet after turning on a modem. It depends on the ISP.

It is not a home page and IE on Windows Phone does not have a homepage.

I had the same experience with my broadband provider in India. **There is nothing you can do about it.** You can contact your ISP if you want. But I doubt they will remove it as they get income from it.

Comment: That sounds depressing, but you seem to be saying the provider has a way to remove it in some kind of way...

Comment: @user62177541 The internet provider can stop it. In my case, they customer care executive said that it is their company policy and they can do nothing about it. But you can try using browsers with a homepage setting. It didn't work with me. But it may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you open Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 8, it resumes to the tabs that you had opened in your last browsing session. So, in essence, it doesn't have a home page. 
If you close all the tabs, as already noticed according to your question,you're going to get a blank page. But, as you said this does not solve the problem, I recommend that you go under `Settings` in the browser, then delete history.
After that, go under `Settings > advanced settings > manage storage` and delete all the websites that have files stored in the phone, and mark and delete them.

This will, however, affect your saved passwords and other website information like cookies stored on your phone. But this is bound to solve the problem you're having

Comment: I am trying these two steps now so if this ends up helping, though I doubt it will, I will post back. One note is that I see nothing under manage storage after clearing the history. Generally as to my question, I was hoping this was a common problem since obviously AT&T is a big company so I would have thought someone would have seen this, but I am going to try to keep an eye on it and find out more from AT&T and post back with anything I learn.

Comment: Okay, please do notify us when it works, for the benefit of the forum, and accuracy of this question